# How to get job-name from job file in azkaban 3.0

Tags: python, azkaban

We need the job name from Azkaban when trying to schedule a job. Is there any built-in property for that? We are getting the flow name from `${azkaban.job.flowid}`.

Eg: My job file is:

```
type=command
command=python xyz.py ${azkaban.job.attempt} ${azkaban.job.flowid}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Azkaban jobs run with following
Environment variables:

```
{ JOB_OUTPUT_PROP_FILE='xxx',
  JOB_PROP_FILE='xxx',
  JOB_NAME='xxx' }
```

The Job Name can be fetched easily by the following Python snippet:

```
import os

job_name = os.environ["JOB_NAME"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Azkaban job runtime properties are stored in file referred by env variable **JOB_PROP_FILE**. Read this file in your python program and get required properties.

```
import os
azkaban_job_prop_file = os.environ["JOB_PROP_FILE"]
with open(azkaban_job_prop_file,'r') as f:
        print f.readline()
```

we can infer job names from these properties **azkaban.flow.nested.path** and **azkaban.job.metadata.file**

azkaban.flow.nested.path -> Use this if job is part of an embedded DAG.